# SQL Update, same query, different results each time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have an SQL query that I am testing, and running as below, but I noticed that it seemed to be returning different data each time, then i realised it was even returning a different amount of rows when i check if it has worked!! I have run it multiple times and the final select statement will return somewhere between 25-32 rows, but how can this change?

I am using `begin tran` and `rollback tran` to work on the same data, and don't believe this is the issue. Can anyone spot what i have done wrong??

It works on a table(`#AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId`) which is pairs of Id's and sets a flag (IsPrimaryAddress) on the Customer address if it exists in the table and it's pair has the flag set. `#AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId` has already been defined and does not change.

```
    begin tran t1

    select CustomerAddress.IsPrimaryAddress, p1.[Id that is master],p1.[Id to delete], c2.IsPrimaryAddress
    FROM CustomerAddress
    join #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId p1 on CustomerAddress.Id=p1.[Id that is master]
    join CustomerAddress c2 on p1.[Id to delete]=c2.Id
    order by [Id that is master]

    --Update primary address
    UPDATE CustomerAddress
    SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM CustomerAddress
    join #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId p1 on CustomerAddress.Id=p1.[Id that is master]
    join CustomerAddress c2 on p1.[Id to delete]=c2.Id

    select CustomerAddress.IsPrimaryAddress, p1.[Id that is master],p1.[Id to delete], c2.IsPrimaryAddress
    FROM CustomerAddress
    join #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId p1 on CustomerAddress.Id=p1.[Id that is master]
    join CustomerAddress c2 on p1.[Id to delete]=c2.Id
    where CustomerAddress.IsPrimaryAddress=0
     and c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1
    order by [Id that is master]

    rollback tran t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId` table must be holding some pairs where the same `Id that is master` is paired with more than one `Id to delete` and those `Ids to delete` have different matching values of `IsPrimaryAddress` in the `CustomerAddress` table.

At the update stage, such `Id that is master` row's `IsPrimaryAddress` is updated randomly with either 1 or 0, depending upon which matching `Id to delete` row gets chosen to be the source of the new value.

Comment: OF COURSE!!!! This makes perfect sense now that I look at it again. I will ask another question how I can get around this, but do you know if there is a way to have the alternative case 'do nothing', setting to itself does not work as it goes off the first read which gives the wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way that this will not result in the same output on each run would be that either you are doing something else outside of this, somebody else is doing something else outside of this, or there is a possibility this could get wonky if you have more than one open transaction. If it is the latter, and/or to test it, just run `ROLLBACK TRAN` until you get an error stating that there are no open transactions. If you get the error the first time, then you did not have any open.

Comment: Got the error first time, no one else is touching the data as it has all been copied to a separate database so i could play with it. Have run it at least 20-30 times now, different every time... put `go` statements in to make sure it wasn't some weird timing thing, still happening...

Comment: What about your #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId table. Add a select * from #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId in their and see if that is changing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andriy hit the mark though. There are duplicates in the data, and when it hits them, it was setting them back, seems so obvious now, but almost drove me to the ledge yesterday!!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue happens because of temp tables in SQL query. Need to check and drop the temp tables before insert.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTableName') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempTableName;
```