# SQL Update with Case, either assign or do nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Coming off the back of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798022/sql-update-same-query-different-results-each-time), is there a way to put a `CASE` statement into an SQL `UPDATE` that either update's or does nothing. Currently i have the below:

```
UPDATE CustomerAddress
SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM CustomerAddress
join #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId p1 on CustomerAddress.Id=p1.[Id that is master]
join CustomerAddress c2 on p1.[Id to delete]=c2.Id
```

The problem arises on this line:

```
SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 THEN 1 ELSE **0** END
```

When I set it to 0 otherwise. The update should check the first condition, and if so, set to 1, but, if the condition is not met, I don't want to set to 0, I need to retain the original value.

```
SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 THEN 1 ELSE *CustomerAddress.IsPrimary* END
```

Doesn't work however, because it gets the value from the `FROM` statement, rather then the value it has been currently set too. What i want is something like this

```
SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 THEN 1 ELSE *Do nothing* END
```

But this is still an assignment, and tries to set to `NULL`.

Is this above possible?

UPDATE:

Sample data:

pair's of ID's that represent address as so

```
ID to keep  ID to delete
------------------------
10          21
10          22
11          31
12          41
```

I'll focus on what happens with 10. So 10 has `IsPrimaryAddress=0`, 21 has `IsPrimaryAddress=1`, and 22 has `IsPrimaryAddress=0`.

What I believe happens is this (in pseudocode):

Set IsPrimaryAddress = if 21.IsPrimaryAddress=1 then set to 21.IsPrimaryAddress else set to 10.IsPrimaryAddress

So we have set 10.IsPrimaryAddress to 1. Now:

Set IsPrimaryAddress = if 22.IsPrimaryAddress=1 then set to 22.IsPrimaryAddress else set to 10.IsPrimaryAddress

Which i would hope 10.IsPrimaryAddress equals 1. But it appears to get the original value which was 0, and now the update has been lost.

Comment: Can you explain what is different about the value in the `FROM` vs. "the value is has been currently set to"?

Comment: See my comment on your answer, hopefully that will explain what I think is happening.

Comment: Please post sample data in both tables and what you want the source table to look like after. Word problems and theories are difficult to solve.

Comment: If you do a lot of update queries, look into the MERGE statement.  It allows you to explicitly handle what happens when you match/don't match.  Unfortunately Books OnLine is kind of ... I found it more dense than usual on the topic.  Remember "USING" means "JOIN" and it might go faster for you. Check [this](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/24/deprecate-update-from-not-if-i-can-help-it) if you're interested

Comment: @LevinMagruder Thanks i will look into it, I've seen it come up a few times, but to be honest I glanced over it and thought 'I'll come back to this later...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause so that you only update the rows that need updating:

```
UPDATE CustomerAddress c1
  INNER JOIN #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId p1 ON c1.Id = p1.[Id that is master]
  INNER JOIN CustomerAddress c2 ON p1.[Id to delete] = c2.Id
  SET c1.IsPrimaryAddress = 1
  WHERE c2.IsPrimaryAddress = 1
```

Comment: Haha.... this actually works perfectly... it doesn't quite cover whether I can do it with the case statement above, but if no one comes up with a way to do it I'll accept this answer

Comment: @dann.dev This way should also be more efficient, for instance it won't write anything at all if there turn out to be no dependent primary addresses.

Comment: yes it's definitely a better way, had a feeling I have been trying to be too tricky with my SQL lately, didn't think it would be a CASE statement that got me though!

Answer (score 8):

```
SET CustomerAddress.IsPrimaryAddress = 
      CASE 
         WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress=1 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE CustomerAddress.IsPrimaryAddress 
      END
```

PS: I'm not sure about table name but the idea is to return column value itself to leave it unchanged, this is a common practice.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives an error say that `IsPrimaryAddress` is ambiguious, this is because the CustomerAddress table is used twice in the join

Comment: Just prefix by table name, `CustomerAddress` or which is correct?!

Comment: Then I get the problem with Aaron's answer, where it can set the wrong value because it is not looking at the update values, but rather the `From` statement

Comment: You're going to need to show an example because I don't think many people are understanding what you mean.

Comment: I've put some sample data of what I think happens, and I do mean 'think' i am no sql guru, but I have run it several times as above and keep getting different answers that support the theory

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE c
SET IsPrimaryAddress = CASE 
  WHEN c2.IsPrimaryAddress = 1 THEN 1 
  ELSE c.IsPrimaryAddress
END
FROM dbo.CustomerAddress AS c
INNER JOIN #AddressToDeleteMasterOfLesserId AS p1 
  ON c.Id = p1.[Id that is master]
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddress AS c2 
  ON p1.[Id to delete] = c2.Id;
```

Comment: Problem with this is it seems to take a select of the data then work from this for the update. You then get it looking at data that may have been updated along the way, so c(1) is originally 0, gets updated to 1, but then has another check where the case isn't true, falls to `ELSE c.IsPrimaryAddress` which doesn't look at the update data, and set's it back to 0, which is not what I want.

Comment: A single update shouldn't make multiple passes at the same table. Have you proven your theory or is it just a theory? Can you post some sample data in both the base and #temp table that demonstrates this?